# iOS - Color an image multiple times from original source

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cgcontext

I have a slider and I want to make an image brighter or darker depending on the slider value. At the moment I have a greyscale image and I have colored it red on viewDidLoad. When my slider's value is changed, I run the code below.

My understanding of the code is that I load in the original image from the file and store it in myImage. I then set the fill color and then draw myImage into the graphics context with CGContextDrawImage. I then fill the image according to the blend mode set and then set the new image to self.bodyView.image (which is the image visible in the super view).

What seems to be happening is that instead of reloading body.png from the file, it looks like it's just reapplying the effect to the already altered image. Why is this?

Thanks in advance.

```
- (IBAction)bodyBrightnessChanged:(UISlider *)sender {

...
code to set 3 floats called red, green and blue to be values between 0 and 1
...

UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"body.png"];

// Begin a new image context to draw the coloured image onto
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bodyView.image.size);

// Get a reference to the context we created
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

// Set the fill colour
[[UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:1.0] setFill];

// translate/flip the graphics context (for transforming from CG* coords to UI* coords
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, self.bodyView.image.size.height);
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

// set the blend mode and the original image
CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeColor);
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bodyView.image.size.width, self.bodyView.image.size.height);
//CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, self.bodyView.image.CGImage); // This is where we need to set the original image - I think...
CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, myImage.CGImage);

// Set a mask that matches the shape of the image, then draw (colour burn) a coloured rectangle
CGContextClipToMask(context, rect, self.bodyView.image.CGImage);
CGContextAddRect(context, rect);
CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFill);

// Generate a new UIImage from the graphics context we drew onto
UIImage *colouredImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

self.bodyView.image = colouredImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad - the issue was with where I was loading the image from.

I needed to use:

```
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"body.png"];
```

NOT

```
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"body.png"];
```